# spring-data-neo4j basic one-to-many relationship not persisting

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

> **EDIT**: Sample project available on [github](https://github.com/troig/neo4jCustomRepository).

I'm using Neo4J (Rest graph database, hosted in grapheneDb) and Spring Data in our backend project.

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase">
```

I have a simple one-to-many relationship between two entities: `User` and `Stay`.

**EDIT**: I thought this wasn't relevant for the issue, but after seeing a [similar problem](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-735) in SDN4, I think I need to update the question (there is a basic `@NodeEntity` class, and both entities are extending this base class).

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class BasicNodeEntity implements Serializable {

   @GraphId
   private Long nodeId;
}


public class User extends BasicNodeEntity {

  @RelatedTo(type = "HAS_STAY",  direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
  Set<Stay> stays;

  public void addStay(Stay stay) {
     stays.add(stay);
  }
}

public class Stay extends BasicNodeEntity {

   @RelatedTo(type = "HAS_STAY", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
   User user;
}
```

I'm unable to persist more than one stay. The first stay I add to the user is persisted correctly, but just the first one. The next stays added never persists, and I always retrieve the first one.

The method I use to create a new stay is:

```
   @Autowired
   Neo4jOperations template;

   @Transactional
   private void createStay(Stay stay, User user) throws Exception {
      stay = template.save(stay);
      user.addStay(stay);
      template.save(user);
      // If i evaluate user at this point, it contains both stays

      // But if I retrieve the user from the repository, it just contains
      // the first stay, the second one has not persisted.
   }
```

**EDIT**: User modified is retrieved correctly through `UserRepository`.

```
public interface UserRepositoryCustom {}

public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User>, UserRepositoryCustom {    
   User findById(String id);
}

User user = userRepository.findById(userId);
```

*NOTE: I also tried to save through the repository interface instead of the Neo4jTemplate one, but I have the same problem.*

Both entities are correctly saved in the neo4j database, it's just a persistence issue.

I think this should be quite easy, so I'm probably missing something..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Relevant versions:

```
<spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring-data-neo4j.version>3.3.2.RELEASE</spring-data-neo4j.version>
```

There is another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044335/spring-data-neo4j-template-fetch-not-returning-entire-collection) with a very similar problem, but without response so far.

Comment: Where do you get your user from that you add the stay to? does it already have the first stay in the collection?

Comment: Are you using embedded or Neo4j server?

Comment: Hi Michael!Thanks for comment. Please see my edits: User is retrieved correctly through neo4j repository, and yes, it has the first stay. And I'm using `SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase`(hosted in grapheneDB)

Comment: but the stays are two different ones? Do you think you could create a small test-case for this setup?

Comment: Yes, the stays are different. In a few hours I'll create a small project on github to help you to reproduce the error. Thanks again

Comment: Hi Michael. I've created a sample [project on github](https://github.com/troig/neo4jCustomRepository) with the error. I hope this helps you. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi @MichaelHunger! Did you have any chance to look at the sample project? If the example is not clear enough, please let me know. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a tricky thing.

Your **custom equals method** causes two entities which have their node-id set but not yet their uuid-id set, to be equal so that when loading them into a set the set will only contain one.

#### Code in: RelationshipHelper

```
protected Set<Object> createEntitySetFromRelationshipEndNodes(Object entity, final MappingPolicy mappingPolicy, final Class<?> relatedType) {
    final Iterable<Node> nodes = getStatesFromEntity(entity);
    final Set<Object> result = new HashSet<Object>();
    for (final Node otherNode : nodes) {
        Object target = template.createEntityFromState(otherNode, relatedType, mappingPolicy);
        result.add(target);
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you change your code to have an equals/hashcode in your BasicNode entity:

```
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (!(o instanceof BasicNodeEntity)) return false;

      BasicNodeEntity that = (BasicNodeEntity) o;

      if (nodeId != null) {
         if (!nodeId.equals(that.nodeId)) return false;
      } else {
         if (that.nodeId != null) return false;
      }

      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      return nodeId != null ? nodeId.hashCode() : 0;
   }
```

so that entities that have only a nodeId set are comparable

and adapt the subclass methods

```
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (!(o instanceof IdentifiableEntity)) return false;

      IdentifiableEntity entity = (IdentifiableEntity) o;
      //change
      if (!super.equals(o)) return false;

      if (id != null) {
         if (!id.equals(entity.id)) return false;
      } else {
         if (entity.id != null) return false;
      }

      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      //change
      if (super.hashCode() != 0) return super.hashCode();
      return id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
   }
```

Then it works.

Going forward if you are working with Neo4j Server I recommend to you to check out [SDN 4 RC2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RC2/reference/html/) instead which was released on Friday.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael, perfect catch! I was unable to point in the right direction. I've tried in our project and it works like a charm. We've planed to switch to SDN4, thanks for the advise.